# New Line Character and PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt4, qtgui

Using QtGui.QMessageBox to display the messages, warnings and errors.

It seems that QMessageBox doesn't want to work with "\n" new line character when used with html tags

> ```
> message =  "<a href = http://www.google.com> GOOGLE</a> This a line number one.\n This a line number two. \n And this is a line number three."
> ```

is all being displayed as one long line when displayed within QMessageBox.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post your code where you call the message box.

Comment: @sputnix, replace \n with <br>

Comment: "doesn't want to work with `\n` new line character when used with html tags". Did you ever try to use a newline inside an HTML text? Because it's *always* ignored. If you have these kind of doubts you should read some HTML tutorial.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The behaviour you are seeing is entirely as expected. It is part of the HTML 4 spec that, other than inside PRE tags, sequences of whitepsace characters should always be collapsed to a single space. To quote the [relevant part of the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/struct/text.html#h-9.1):

> Note that a sequence of white spaces between words in the source
>   document may result in an entirely different rendered inter-word
>   spacing (except in the case of the PRE element). In particular, user
>   agents should collapse input white space sequences when producing
>   output inter-word space.

So, when you need to insert line-breaks, do it explicitly using the `<br>` tag.

PS:

It's also worth noting here that Qt's text widgets only support a limited set of HTML tags, attributes and CSS properties. For full details, see the [Supported HTML Subset](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/richtext-html-subset.html) in the Qt docs.